# Syntax for setting checkbox value(as checked) in dojo dynamically

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

How to **set the value of a check-box to checked dynamically  using dojo**? In dojo toolkit site I saw it was written to use  key value pair for setting the checkboxWidget but am unsure about the approach. Can someone please suggest?

Here is my approach but it doesnt work .How can I fix this?:

```
 checkboxWidget.set("","checked");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use set to assign a value to a property, the first parameter is the property name followed by the value.

```
checkboxWidget.set("checked", checkedValue);
```